# ContourPlot from a different view

Tags: plotting

Consider a function of $z=f(x,y)$ I want to have a `ContourPlot` with vertical axis as `z` and horizontal `y` and contour of `x`. How can I do that? I would appreciate if you could explain with a simple example.

P.S. The functional does not necessarily have an analytical inverse.

Comment: Look up `SliceContourPlot3D[]`.

Comment: @J.M. this is 3D, I need 2D

Comment: `ContourPlot[ Evaluate@Table[z - f[x, y]==0, {x, xlevelsList}], {y, ymin, 
  ymax}, {z, zmin, zmax}]`?

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to create a table of values of your function:

```
tab = Flatten[Table[{y,f[x,y],x},{x,xmin,xmax,xstep},{y,ymin,ymax,ystep}],1]
```

(With some reasonable values for `xmin`, `xmax`, `xstep`, `ymin`, `ymax`, `ystep`)

You can then create a contour plot with `ListContourPlot`:

```
ListContourPlot[tab]
```

Obviously this requires a bit of manual fiddling to choose parameters which look good, but it should work.